How to find singular solutions that cannot be obtained from general solution of nonlinear differential equation $y''=yy'/x^2$
I rewrote the above equation as
$$x^2y''=yxy'.$$
Then I used a change of variable $x=e^t; x*dy/dx=dt$; and $x^2*y''(x)=y''(t)-y'(t). $
And I get
$$y''(t)-y'(t)=yy'(t).$$
Then I used substitution
$$u(y)=y'(t), y''(x)=(du/dy)*dy/dt=u'(y)u(y).$$
This gave the first order equation
$$uu'-u = y*u.$$
I rewrote the equation and factored to:
$$u(u'-1-y)=0$$
Setting each term to $0$, I got $u=y'=0$.  Thus $y=c_3$, $c_3$ arbitrary constant. Checks with book.
Also, $(u'-1-y)=0, or y''(t) = y+1.$
Book has a second solution as $y=-2/(c_4+\ln(x))-1$ but I don't see a substitution that allows that solution. Please provide and comments.  Thanks.

Use some Latex please

When you say $y''(t) = y+1$, you actually mean $du/dy = y+1$, which is not the same thing.

$y''=yy'/x^2$ is not equivalent to $x^2y''=yxy'.$

I'd recommend denoting $t$-derivatives with dot notation instead, e.g. $\dot{y}=xy'$ (\dot{y}=xy'). It would make mistakes much easier to avoid.

Using u’ = du/dy = (dy/dx)(dx/dt)
